# What does it mean, terminology-wise, for a set of formulas to be positive in Q?

Tags: model-theory

When you say "$S$ is a positive sentence (of first order logic)," it means $S$ contains only the symbols { ∧ ∨ ∃ ∀ }, but not ¬. My understanding is that the set of relation symbols in question are { ¬ ∧ ∨ ∃ ∀ }, and "positive" means "can't use ¬".

But what does it mean for a set Γ of formulas to be positive in some arbitrary set $Q$? I found this wording [here (pdf)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-9/issue-1/Properties-preserved-under-homomorphism/pjm/1103039459.pdf) stating:

> PROPOSITION 1. If a set Γ of formulas is positive in all the relation
> symbols in a set Q, then Γ is increasing in Q.

My best understanding is that it means

1. Every formula in Γ is positive
2. with "positive" meaning it contains only symbols in $Q$ except ¬.

I'm probably misunderstanding here, but what does "positive" mean if $Q$ doesn't include ¬ in the first place? For example, when $Q$ is { = } for some language about equality -- this $Q$ is a set of relation symbols from which ¬ is absent.

Comment: Normally positive might mean monotone Boolean functions representable by propositional wffs. If you have $\lnot$ connective in your logical symbols and wffs, then its corresponding Boolean function cannot be monotone. See ref [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness#Characterization_of_functional_completeness) for monotone connectives for detail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbols $\forall, \exists, \land, \lor, \lnot$ are *not* relation symbols: they are logical connectives. Relation symbols are the things like $\leq$ or $P$ that come in a language / signature and are used to form atomic formulas.

So your guess doesn't make any sense: $Q$ is a set of relation symbols, and $\lnot$ is not a relation symbol, so it could not be in $Q$.

Instead, we say that a formula is positive in a relation $R$ if every instance of $R$ appears within the scope of an even number of negations. For example, $R(y,y)\lor \lnot \exists x\, (P(x)\land \lnot R(x,y))$ is positive in $R$ but not positive in $P$. Equivalently, if you "push all the negations inside", then no instance of $R$ appears negated. For example, the formula above is equivalent to $R(y,y)\lor \forall x\,(\lnot P(x)\lor R(x,y))$.

Now we say a set of formulas $\Gamma$ is positive in a set of relation symbols $Q$ if every formula in $\Gamma$ is positive in every relation symbol in $Q$.